# Can not make qgis.db private copy

Tags: qgis, error, ubuntu, database

I've just installed QGIS 2.0.1 on Ubuntu and the above error message appears.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?  I think I need to change the permissions of the relevant folder, but I'm not certain.

Comment: The above answer worked like a charm for me. Thankyou.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Delete or change ownership](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Message-Can-not-make-qgis-db-private-copy-td5064236.html) of the .qgis2 folder.

```
sudo rm -rf .qgis2
#or
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername .qgis2
```